# Get List of COM+ services running on remote servers?

Tags: remote-server, com+

How I can get list COM+ services running on remote servers? and how to set identity to com+ server remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [COM+ Administration API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/comadmincatalog) to accomplish this. It allows you to administer services in the local or remote catalog. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/setting-properties-and-saving-changes-to-the-com--catalog) article for guidance on how to get and set properties. Here's a simple example written in C#. You will add a reference to the *COM + 1.0 Admin Type Library*

```
using COMAdmin;

COMAdminCatalogCollection applications;
COMAdminCatalog catalog;

catalog = new COMAdminCatalog();
// To connect to a remote server you would user the following
catalog.Connect(serverName); 

applications = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)catalog.GetCollection("Applications");
            applications.Populate();

foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject application in applications)
{
    //do something with the application
    if (application.Name.Equals("MyAppName"))
    {
        application.Value["Identity"] = @"MACHINE\UserName";
        application.Value["Password"] = @"UserPassword";
    }

}
```